# How to convert Hexadecimal to Decimal?

Tags: c, cygwin, hex, decimal

I have different hexadecimal data are coming and stored into an integer type register.

When I use fprint I can see the following:

```
0x3076
0x307c
.
.
.
```

However, I would like to show a Decimal version of above-mention Hex data as follows.

```
12406
12412
.
.
.
```

In theory, let's say for the first value you do the following to convert it to decimal.

```
(6* 16^0)+(7 * 16^1)+(0*16^2)+(3*16^3)=6 + 112+ 0 + 12288 = 12406
```

So IF I have the character-based version of "0x3076" and also, IF I am able to get each single characters 6 - 7 - 0 - 3, I can calculate the decimal amount!

So, I decided to divide "3076" by 1000. I was expected to get 3, but I got TWO characters instead! however, if I was able to get 3 for the remainder of "307c" I am not able to get "C". If it was decimal this might work not hex!

Also, I tried "`strtol`" command. As I use Cygwin to compile my code, I am not sure where the error is! What did I do wrong?

So, I just need to find a way to get EACH SINGLE character out of the HEX data!

Any idea please?

P.S.

Here is my code in order to help you to give me an idea.

```
   int get_readings(int source, int phase, int max_tries)
{
    uint8_t buf[MAX_IEC1107_MSG_BODY];
    uint8_t inbuf[MAX_IEC1107_MSG_BODY];
    int inlen;
    uint8_t *s;
    int32_t value;
    int status;
    double voltage;
    double current;
    double active_power;
    double reactive_power;
    double apparent_power;
    double power_factor;
    double frequency;

    s = buf;
    *s++ = HOST_CMD_GET_READINGS_PHASE_1 + phase;
    *s++ = 0x00;
    if (max_tries != 1)
        meter_set_max_tries(&emeter[source].meter_msg, max_tries);
    if (meter_exchange(&emeter[source].meter_msg, buf, 2, inbuf, &inlen)
        &&
        inbuf[1] != 0xFF)
    {
        emeter[source].no_response = FALSE;
        s = inbuf;
        /* Get current readings */
        value = (s[3] << 8) | s[2];

        fprint(stderr, "value:" %p\n, value); // this give me HEX code
```

.
.
.

Comment: If the number is in an integer variable then it's not stored in hex. You're just (presumably?) printing it out as hex with fprintf, using the %x specifier. Try printing the same numbers with %u instead.

Comment: You really must post your code, and your exact input and output, if you want to know why it is wrong.

Comment: @Weather Vane; I just added my code. Thanks!

Comment: @ ooga: When I use other than "%p" I will get wrong number! How do I know? Because it should give me some numbers around 120 V which is my voltage!

Comment: Why is this tagged _cygwin_? It seems to be just a question about Standard C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only with the following line I could solve the issue!

```
fprintf(stderr, "Voltage: %.2f\n", value/100.00);
```

value was shown as HEX as I used to use %p! Then I changed to x! and as I need to have 124.06 not 12406, in other words 2 decimal points, I added .2f!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 11):

When reading in a string representing a number in hexadecimal, use `strtol()` to convert it to a long.  Then if you want to print the number in decimal, use `printf()` with a `%d` format specifier.

```
char num[]="0x3076";
long n = strtol(num, NULL, 16);
printf("n=%ld\n", n);  // prints 12406
```

Once you read in the strings as longs using `strtol` and operate on the longs, the math should work itself out.

Comment: @ dbush & VBLUEPIXY unfortunately this gives me 0!

Comment: @user3092919 I just ran this and got 12406.  What does your test code look like?

Comment: That can only convert up to max `LONG_MAX`. On 32bit systems usually this can be a problem when reading RFID tags in hexa and trying to convert them into human readable decimal format.

Comment: many thanks for the answer @dbush. I have a probably newbie question: why do we have to write `char num[]="0x3076";` and not simply `char num="0x3076";`? What does the `[]` mean?

Comment: Strings aren't a type in in C. Strings in C are viewed as arrays of chars, hence the square brackets.

Comment: @ecjb : A string literal is of type `char*`, so you could also write `char const* num="..."`. This is how I would write it, or, since you are not going re-assign `num`, as `char const*const num="..."`.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned n;
sscanf("0x3076", "%x", &n);
printf("%u\n", n);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) for printing only:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  int a=0;
  scanf("%x",&a);
  printf("%d\n",a);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

2) for calculation use:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int CharToDec(char c){
  if(c>='0' && c<='9') return c-'0';
  if(c>='a' && c<='f') return c-'a'+10;
  if(c>='A' && c<='F') return c-'A'+10;
  return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char H[10];
  char *P;
  int p=1,d=0;
  printf("Entrez Hexadecimale nombre:");
  scanf("%s",H);
  for(P=H;*P;P++);
  for(P--;P>=H;P--){
    d = d + (CharToDec(*P) * p);
    p =  p*16;
  }
  printf("%d\n",d);
system("pause");
return 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing "integer" and "decimal" -- an "integer" is a number stored in a register or variable, while a "decimal" is a string of characters that represent a number in base 10.

So converting from hexadecimal to decimal is a two-step process.  You first convert the hexadecimal to integer (which you appear to have done, with your "In theory" equation).  You then convert the integer to decimal.

There are lots of ways to do either of these tasks,  `strtol` and `scanf` will convert either hexadecimal or decimal to integer.  `printf` can convert integer to either hexedecimal or decimal.  Or you can write your own routines that manipulate characters to do either of these things.

Comment: "*a "decimal" is a string of characters*" what? You might like to update yourself here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_data_type#Standard_formats

Comment: @alk: That agrees perfectly with what I said -- a decimal number is a string of characters representing a number in base 10.  How you encode those characters as bits on a computer is another question.

Comment: @ Chris:  I still have not figured it out how to get single character to convert it to decimal. The rest would be much easier thought!

Comment: @user3092919:  To convert a single character to an integer, you generally use a lookup table -- there are only 10 or 16 valid (hex) characters that can appear in a number.  Alternately, if you know your characters are ASCII you can use arithemetic on ascii codes -- so `ch - '0'` will convert the character `ch` to an integer if it is a decimal digit.  `ch - 'a' + 10` works for hex digits a..f