# How to convert hexadecimal to decimal recursively

Tags: c++, hex, radix, converters

I need to do this convertion but have no clue. Can someone help me? I need this to complete a calculator of base convertion. I also need that the function return a integer to convert to use in my others functions.

PS: sorry for my bad english.

i expect that 11F to be an integer 287.

Comment: What is you expectation regarding **"recursively"**? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at existing questions like [How to convert Hexadecimal to Decimal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079978/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-to-decimal) or [Converting Hexadecimal to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031159/converting-hexadecimal-to-decimal) to understand how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Hexadecimal to Decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031159/converting-hexadecimal-to-decimal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's something with recursion:

```
int hexToBase10(const std::string& number, size_t pos = 0) {
   if (pos == number.length())
       return 0;
   char digit = number[number.size() - pos - 1];
   int add = digit >= '0' && digit <= '9' ? digit - '0'
                                          : digit - 'A' + 10;
   return 16 * hexToBase10(number, pos + 1) + add;
}
```

Call it this way:

```
hexToBase10("11F");  // 287
```

Btw, it seems to be more safe to use `std::hex`.

Comment: You should **note:** that the hex string cannot include the prefixes `"0x"` or `"0X"` and the hex-characters must be upper-case (you can address the latter by including `<cctype>` and using `std::tolower()` in your function). You can address the former in the caller or in a wrapper to your function that uses `.find()` to check for `'x'` or `'X'` and advances past the prefix. (for instance try converting `"11f"` or `"0x11F"`) That said, you did answer the "recursive" aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Provided it fits into at most `unsigned long long`, you can use `strtoul`/`strtoull` from stdlib.h to parse it from a base-16 string into an integer.

You can then simply print that integer in base 10.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char const *hex = "11F";
    char *endptr;
    unsigned long ul = strtoul(hex,&endptr,16);
    printf("%lu\n", ul);
}
```

Comment: Only problem here is a lack of recursion, a requirement I can't imagine the point of.

Comment: Probably classwork to get the student familiar with the concept.